# Explain to me this filter code - javascript

Tags: javascript, filter

Its a question in an exam past paper:

```
...
var filter = /^([a-zA-Z]){2}[0-9]$/;
if (!filter.test(val)){
...
```

Can someone please explain to me:

1. the content stored in the var, explain each element in it
2. what does .test do?

Thanks in advance

Edit:
(Full function)

```
function validateField(val)
{
    var filter = /^([a-zA-Z]){2}[0-9]$/;
    if (!filter.test(val))
    {
        alert('Please enter correct value');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: That code is testing whether `val` matches the `filter` regular expression.

Comment: My RegExp is rusty, but I think the pattern tries to match something that begins with 2 letters and a number.

Comment: @Joseph the Dreamer: that's pretty close: not *begins*, but the whole string *consists of* 2 letters followed by a number

Comment: Shorter: `/^[a-z]{2}\d$/i`

Comment: @Ouz Kedz: pro-search-pattern: "javascript %functionname% function mdn" in google. In this case it's "[javascript test function mdn](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=javascript+test+function+mdn&aq=f&oq=javascript+test+function+mdn&aqs=chrome.0.57.187j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)" and check the Mozilla Developers Network wiki page with function description

Comment: @zerkms oh! yah, you're right :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question:** The content stored in the var, explain each element in it?
**Answer:** `/^([a-zA-Z]){2}[0-9]$/` this is a regular expression.

^([a-zA-Z]){2}

`^` means start with
`([a-zA-Z])` means the input must be lower case character a-z and upper case character A-Z 
`{2}` means must be two characters.

[0-9]$
[0-9] means number in 0 to 9 range and $ means must be end with this number.

Therefore `/^([a-zA-Z]){2}[0-9]$/` means

the input should be start with two lower or upper case a-z|A-Z characters and end with a number from 0 to 9.

**Question:** What does .test do?
**Answer:** The test() method tests for a match in a string.
This method returns true if it finds a match, otherwise it returns false.

Finally I recommend you to have a look http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html. It contains the tutorial of regular expression.

Comment: Oh right, now I heard about Regular Expressions. Missed that lecture. Now I know what I should search for. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The String in the `filter` is a Regular Expression, so have a look at: http://www.regular-expressions.info

with the `if(!filter.test(val))`it will test the value (`val`) is a valid form of the regular expression you made the line above. You can test your regular expression here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know what to search. I'll take a close look at RegExpr